# How to get the client username with Waffle?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, waffle

I'm running `Tomcat 7` on `Windows 7`. All clients are running `Windows 7` too  .

I'm trying to print the client username on a `test.jsp` page so I use `Waffle` . Here is the `WEB-INF/web.xml`

```
 <filter>
  <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>impersonate</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
```

Here is my `test.jsp`

```
<% 
    String userId = Secur32Util.getUserNameEx(Secur32.EXTENDED_NAME_FORMAT.NameSamCompatible); 
    out.println(userId); 
%>
```

However it always prints the `server` computer username . I tried it on many `client` machines, and it always printed the `server` but not the `client`  userid

Why? How to correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic is: `$pageContext.request.remoteUser`

Comment: Thank you. However this method triggers a pop-up window that requires a client to type in the userid and password. This defeats the purpose. I don't even need waffle. I could simply ask the user to type in a userid in a text field. I want to get the userid without the client having to go though any extra steps

Comment: @john If so either Waffle is broken or you are doing something wrong.

Comment: It works fine with Internet Explorer only. Chrome and Firefox display pop-up authentication windows.

Comment: @john as I have told, you are doing something wrong. You have to tell Firefox to perform SPNEGO auth and it will do what you need. Modify `network.negotiate-auth.trusted-uris` and `network.negotiate-auth.delegation-uris` and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

First, put waffle-api.jar on your project classpath. then put this xml code on your web.xml.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>waffle.servlet.NegotiateSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>principalFormat</param-name>
        <param-value>fqn</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>roleFormat</param-name>
        <param-value>both</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>allowGuestLogin</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>securityFilterProviders</param-name>
        <param-value>
        waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider
        waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.NegotiateSecurityFilterProvider/protocols</param-name>
        <param-value>
        Negotiate
        NTLM
    </param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>waffle.servlet.spi.BasicSecurityFilterProvider/realm</param-name>
        <param-value>WaffleFilterDemo</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SecurityFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and use below code to get your clients username ;

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)Executions.getCurrent().getNativeRequest();
String user = request.getRemoteUser();
```

for more detail you can visit :

https://github.com/dblock/waffle

Credit Goes to [klepon](http://forum.zkoss.org/users/59516/kleponboy/)

### Resource Link:

1. http://forum.zkoss.org/question/96532/get-clients-username/
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891022/2293534

Comment: Thank you very much. I was aware of the `getRemoteUser()` method. However, it requires the client to authenticate with userid and password. Maybe I should restate my question. I need to get the client userid  without the client having to go through authentication. However, the `getRemoteUser()` triggers a pop-up with userid and password form

Comment: This pop-up window defeats the purpose. The user types in the userid so that it could be printed on the page. I don't even need waffle for this

Comment: you have to use ntlm protocol in order to use waffle without entering credentials. it works for me.

Comment: @john Did you got any solution for this?